# Bootstrap 3 Footer inline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to fix my footer. Here is my problem, I am planning to put Copyright on the left side and social media icons on the right side. Currently, they are showing in the two different lines. I was wondering is there anyway I can make them put into one same line?

Here is my code:

```html
   <!-- Footer -->
   <footer>
   <hr>
    <div class="container text-center">
     <div class="page-header text-center">
      <h3>Subscribe for special offer <small>Enter your information</small></h3>
     </div>

     <form action="" class="form-inline" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="phone_no">Phone Number (Type only the numbers)</label>
       <input type="text" name="num" data-validation="number" 
    data-validation-allowing="negative,number" input name="color" 
    data-validation="number" datavalidation-ignore="$" required="required" class="form-control" 
    id="phone_no" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" pattern="\d*">
       <!--<input type="tel" id="phone_no" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required="required">-->
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
      <hr>
     </form> <!--End form-->

     <hr>
     <div class="copyright" style="text-align: left;">
      <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2016</p>
     </div>
     <div class="social media" style="text-align: right;">
     <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>

    </div> <!--End Container-->

  </footer>




  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
     $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(e) {
         var $anchor = $(this);
         
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
         }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo') //add/remove for smooth scroll;
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
 </script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<!-- Footer -->
 <footer>
  <hr>
   <div class="container text-center">
     <h3>Subscribe for special offer <small>Enter your information</small></h3>
   </div>

   <form action="" class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
     </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
     </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone_no">Phone Number (format: XXXXXXXXXX)</label>
        <input type="text" name="num" data-validation="number" 
    data-validation-allowing="negative,number" input name="color" 
    data-validation="number" datavalidation-ignore="$" required="required" class="form-control" 
    id="phone_no" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" pattern="\d*">
                    <!--<input type="tel" id="phone_no" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required="required">-->

     </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
     <hr>
    </form> <!--End form-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="copyright">
       <p class="navbar-text pull-left">&copy; Copyright @ 2016</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bootsnipp"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/bootsnipp"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/+Bootsnipp-page"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
      <a href="mailto:bootsnipp@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div> <!--End row-->

   </div> <!--End Container-->

</footer>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamrico/ng6xrsq5/

Answer (score 0):

Change width of facebook

```html
   <!-- Footer -->
   <footer>
   <hr>
    <div class="container text-center">
     <div class="page-header text-center">
      <h3>Subscribe for special offer <small>Enter your information</small></h3>
     </div>

     <form action="" class="form-inline" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="phone_no">Phone Number (Type only the numbers)</label>
       <input type="text" name="num" data-validation="number" 
    data-validation-allowing="negative,number" input name="color" 
    data-validation="number" datavalidation-ignore="$" required="required" class="form-control" 
    id="phone_no" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10" pattern="\d*">
       <!--<input type="tel" id="phone_no" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" required="required">-->
      </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
      <hr>
     </form> <!--End form-->

     <hr>
     <div class="copyright" style="float: left;">
      <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2016</p>
     </div>
     <div class="social media" style="float: right;">
     <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>

    </div> <!--End Container-->

  </footer>




  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function() {
     $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(e) {
         var $anchor = $(this);
         
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
             scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
         }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo') //add/remove for smooth scroll;
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
 </script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5a33902e83.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```